# List of interfaces from List of implementation class

Tags: java, interface

I have the following code:

```
List<MassEditionObject> objects = getProjects();
```

where `MassEditionObject` is an interface that is implemented by the `Project` class.

`getProjects()` returns `List<Project>`, which seems like it should be fine because Project is a MassEditionObject.

However, Eclipse is giving me this error:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Project> to List<MassEditionObject>`

I understand the general idea of interfaces and how to use them, I'm just not sure **why** this is invalid.

Thanks, and sorry if this question has been posted. I searched and found similar situations but none that answered this problem.

Comment: Did you try to typecast the return value from getProjects() to List<MassEdittionObject>; some thing like this 
List<TestB> variable = (List<TestB>)(List<?>) collectionOfListA;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the proper generics version of this, it would be

```
List<? extends MassEditionObject> objects = getProjects();
```

You should read up on generics, it can be a bit complicated sometimes.
Of course if you know that there will be a `List<Project>` returned, you could just that as the type. But if you had a class `ProjectB` that also implemented `MassEditionObject` they would both be acceptable.

```
List<? extends MassEditionObject> objects = getProjects();   // Return List<Project>
List<? extends MassEditionObject> objects2 = getProjectsB(); // Return List<ProjectB>
```

Comment: Ah, very nice! I did not know you could use the wildcard with interfaces.

Comment: Yea, the syntax is a bit confusing at first.

Comment: However note that using a wildcard as a return type is [not recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html), as it "forces the caller to deal with wildcards". So wildcards are something we don't really want to throw around willy-nilly.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the contrary actually.

`List<Project> object = getProjects()` where `getProjects()` returns a `List<MassEditionObject>`.

**A `Project` is a `MassEditionObject`. A `MassEditionObject` is not necessarily a `Project`.**

Since my code above doesn't rly make sense in your case, you could just do

`List<Project> object = getProjects()` with the same `getProjects` you have now.

Or **see @Kayaman**'s answer also.

Answer (score 0):

change the return type to getObjects to

```
public List<? extends Project> getObjects();
```

and u can use it like this

```
List<Project> objs = getObjects();

List<MassEditionObject> mObjs = (List<MassEditionObject>)getObjects();
```